# What are pros / cons to add UIView to cell vs cell.contentView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell`. How should I add a subview to it? I have seen many example to add subview to the `contentView`, but why not directly to the `cell`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it, but  If you want to customize cells by adding custom view, you should add them to the contentView in order to get them animated along the table animations

Answer (score 0):

When you add a custom view to contentView or assigning to contentView handles framing resizing  part ,animation part and when editing mode is ON (`tableView.editing = YES;`) tableview tries to operate with views of itself meaning contentView, accessoryView. So when you want to add something to the table view and let control be given to tableView go for contentView